# solr: use filter if field contains value

Tags: search, solr, filter, conditional-statements

Trying to find solution to build query so I can filter certain docs like so:

```
if category = xyz 
   -created:[* TO NOW-7DAY/DAY]
else 
   no filtering
```

Is that generally possible or will I need to do this after receiving the results?
And if possible, of course, how?

Answer (score 2):

You can query for either the correct category and the time sequence you want, or documents with another category than the one required for the first match.

```
(category:xyz AND -created[* TO NOW-7DAY/DAY]) OR -category:xyz
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @NSQuamber.java This is actually an answer to the question. I have expanded the text and removed the question mark to make that clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [Switch parser](http://solr.pl/en/2013/06/03/switch-query-parser-quick-look/) from recent Solr. I also published [an example that's used in multi-field advanced search](https://gist.github.com/arafalov/5e04884e5aefaf46678c). Notice that you can switch on specific value, presence of (any) value and missing value.